# how to attach internal memory file in android

Tags: android, email, attachment, internal-storage

I have created one pdf dynamically and saved into application internal memory under one folder.
Now i want to share that pdf over mail or other available sharing options.

I am facing

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:560)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:376)
```

Below one is my code

Manifest File

```
<provider
            android:authorities="mypkgName.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

file_paths.xml: it is under res /xml/file_paths

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="media"/>
    <files-path path="app_PDF_Export/" name="Report.pdf" />
    <files-path path="/" name="allfiles" />
</paths>
```

Java file

```
File newFile = new File(getActivity().getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator +   Constants.folderName, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.pdf_name) + ".pdf");
//
  Uri sharedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getPackageName(), newFile);
            PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (list.size() < 1) {
                return;
            }
            String packageName = list.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;

            getActivity(). grantUriPermission(packageName, sharedFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sharedFileUri );
```

Any one suggest me where am doing wrong
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the complete Java stack trace, not just the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:authorities="mypkgName.fileprovider"
```

does not match:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getPackageName(), newFile);
```

As a result, `FileProvder` cannot find the `ContentProvider` to read its XML metadata. You need to pass in the proper authority string to `getUriForFile()`.

Since you set `android:authorities` to `"mypkgName.fileprovider"`, use:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "mypkgName.fileprovider", newFile);
```

(`getApplicationContext()` is pointless here)

Comment: Can you please give me brief description over code base, its  helpful for me

Comment: I have crated file_paths xml is under res.If we carte under raw how we can access in manifest file

Comment: But Still am facing Below issue java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/mypckageame/export_folder/Psoriasis_Symptom_Repor‌​t.pdf at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.g‌​etUriForFile(FilePro‌​vider.java:678) at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FilePr‌​ovider.java:377)

Comment: @Pinki: That is because you saved your file in an unsupported location. Use `getFilesDir()`, and subdirectories under it, to be able to serve files using `<files-path>`.